# File.Move, why do i get a FileNotFoundException? The file exist

Tags: .net, filenotfoundexception

Its extremely weird since the program is iterating the file! outfolder  and infolder are both in H:/ my external HD using windows 7. The idea is to move all folders that only contain files with the extention db and svn-base. When i try to move the folder i get an exception. VS2010 tells me it cant find the folder specified in dir. This code is iterating through dir so how can it not find it! this is weird.

```
        string []theExt = new string[] { "db", "svn-base" };
        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(infolder))
        {
            bool hit = false;
            if (Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Count() > 0)
                continue;
            foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                var ext = Path.GetExtension(f).Substring(1);
                if(theExt.Contains(ext) == false)
                {
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hit)
            {
                var dst = outfolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(dir);
                File.Move(dir, outfolder); //FileNotFoundException: Could not find file dir.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do realise you have an unused variable in `dst` there, right?

Comment: Yeah, it was there bc after the error i checked if it wanted a dir+filename vs a dir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are trying to move a whole directory using [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) which expects a filename.

Try using [Directory.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) instead since that allow you to move entire folders around.

Comment: d'oh. Wow, i had no idea there was a difference or even that directory.move exists